# I'm getting an error with my code "layer = <CALayer: ADRESS>>'s window is not equal to <UIImagePickerController: ADRESS>'s view's window!"

Tags: ios, swift, nsarray, uiimagepickercontroller

I am trying to call the takePhoto function and use an `imagePickerController()` method to try and segue to a different view controller that contains an `UIIMageView`.

I am trying to pass the photo taken to the new view controller/ class but I receive the error mentioned in the title.

```
@IBAction func takePhoto(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(UIImagePickerController.SourceType.camera) {
        let imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()
        imagePicker.delegate = self
        imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerController.SourceType.camera
        imagePicker.allowsEditing = false

        self.present(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)

    }
 self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "postSegue", sender: self)
}
```

Comment: Why you are calling `self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "postSegue", sender: self)` after presenting the image picker ?

Comment: Yeah i wasnt really sure where else to call it since you cant perform segue in a completion handler...

Comment: You need to implement image picker delegate methods and write the post segue inside that.